# Outlook in darkmode messes with the css

Tags: html-email, email-client

I have a emailTemplate that I want to have a light background.
But Outlook in darkMode messes the css up. Sure there is a switch in outlook to "turn the ligths on" but I want to have white background all the time because everyone that gets the email will not know how to do that switch.

I have tried to add bgcolor to the table tag and the td tag and added backgroundColor to inline style, but without success.

I have also tried to force the button to have the same yellow color in darkmode, but it switches no matter what.
I have also tried to search the internet but cant anything that covers outlook darkmode.

https://litmus.com/blog/email-designers-next-challenge-apple-dark-mode

```
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width:70%;" align="center" border="0"      cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">    <tbody>      <tr>        <td bgcolor="#ffffff">

<tr>
                        <td align="center" style="
                            display: inline-block;
                            background-color: #ffdd00;
                            border-radius: 3px;
                            padding: 18px 0px;
                            width: 100%;
                            text-align: center;
                            cursor: pointer;
                            ">
                          <a href="https://my.hogia.se" target="_blank" style="
                             text-decoration: none;
                             text-transform: uppercase;
                             color: #000;
                             font-family: Lato, Trebuchet, Verdana, Tahoma, Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial;
                             font-weight: 700;
                             font-size: 14px;
                             letter-spacing: 0.0625em;">Kom igång</a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
```

StandardMode:
[image]

DarkdMode:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `bgcolor` and/or `background-color` on the body tag?

Comment: I have tried both yes.

Comment: add in your code please so we can have a look properly. Without code its like shooting in the dark(mode)

Comment: Haha "in the dark(mode)" :D. Well the code I have provided is the elements that surrounding the content, the rest is not relevant to the background. I can provide code to the button as well and how it gets it color, but because the "dark mode" takes over the problem is the how outlook handles colors in darkmode and how to make upp for that.

Comment: For anyone that reads this, I got it to work in outlook darkmode with the !important flag and style tag, like this:
.lightTheme {
background: #ffffff !important;
color: #000 !important;
}
<body class="lightTheme">
<table class="lightTheme" style="width:70%;" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

But Win10 Mail DarkMode did not work, it still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook365 and Outlook.com dark mode can't be overridden because Microsoft adds !important inline to every background color it finds including the system. I think they added this in June 2021.